# Brother MFC440CN printer on 19.10

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I have had an MFC440CN working on both 18.04 and 19.04, but on upgrading to 19.10 the printer stopped working. I have tried to reinstall the printer driver using the Brother provided method and I get an error message

```
lpadmin: Unable to open PPD "/tmp/013bc5e0992f3": Illegal option keyword string on line 229
```

however, the process continues. When I try to do a test print I get

```
lpadmin: Unable to open PPD "/usr/share/cups/model/brmfc440cn.ppd": Illegal option keyword string on line 229.
```

Examining that file around line 229 I see

```
*OpenGroup: Image Type

*%=== Document ================================

*OpenUI *BRDocument/ Image Type: PickOne

*OrderDependency: 21 AnySetup *BRDocument

*DefaultBRDocument: Photo

*BRDocument Photo/Photo: ""

*BRDocument Graphics/Graphics: ""

*BRDocument custom/custom: "" 

*CloseUI: *BRDocument
```

Line 229 is the second to last one.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to correct this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem with ubuntu 20,04 beta. Yesterday I installed the official 20.04 and installed the driver using "linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1". All worked on first try.

Comment: I had a Brother MFC-J5335DW powered up whilst I upgraded a laptop to 20.04. I was (delightfully) surprised when, on completion, I found that the print driver had been automatically installed. The scanner function also worked. Well done, whoever provided the updater. When I powered up the 440CN it was trivial to add that printer too - but the scanning function on that device didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There's been no response to my question so, in desperation, I did the following - and the printer worked! (My requirements of the printer are pretty basic, it's quite possible that this procedure would fail for anyone with more complex needs.)

As the file is a system file, it is necessary to invoke `sudo` (I used `sudo su`)

1. Renamed the file `/usr/share/cups/model/brmfc440cn.ppd` as
   `/usr/share/cups/model/brmfc440cnOLD.ppd`
2. Edited the new version by removing **all** the lines quoted in the
   question
3. Saving the edited file as `/usr/share/cups/model/brmfc440cn.ppd` ie
   the original file has been replaced by an edited version but a copy
   of it has been saved under a new name
4. Via the settings windows adding the printer
5. Touching wood (this may not be absolutely necessary)
6. Print a random page from a random document.

It worked for me, perhaps it will for you.